# Regex split line with occasional stringwrapper - can´t understand regex

Tags: java, regex, coldfusion

I have a problem finding the error in a csv-importer. Any resolution is great.

The csv has such lines.... as you see, the quotation marks are not around all fields.
1: "Kunde";"Vtr";"Name"
2: 10000000;29;"xyz Company"

The following regex shall deliver an array with all field values to import.

`line.split(";(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1)`

And I have to describe, that I don´t understand this regex...

Problem seems to be, that the quotation marks are not always deleted. So my insert does '"xyz Company"', which is wrong.

Additional, the whole procedure is totally slow. We have to import millions of lines... and the importer is running hours.... not nice. 
Any idea, on how to optimize the regex for that; that seems to be the biggest bottleneck.

Comment: Don't use _split_ for delimiter's that you don't know are in the proper place. Use a regex to match all into an array. Want that ?

Comment: That regex is very unfortunate and is known to cause slowdown due to a high amount of nested quantifiers within that lookahead. You should use some full-fledged CSV parser for better efficiency.

Comment: Note that if you expand your regex a bit `; (?= ( [^"] " [^"] " ) [^"] $ )` you'll notice that there is no quantifier that will take that assertion to the end of the string. So, it will never match anything.

Comment: @christian-Küpers I had a similar issues & switched to use OpenCSV. There are some ColdFusion samples online if you search. I wrote a UDF to convert a delimited file to a query. https://gist.github.com/JamoCA/6062864 (NOTE: This solution even works if quoted values have carriage breaks in the data or if your rows of data are of inconsistent length.)

Comment: @christian-Küpers - Are you using regex's because your database import utilities don't work? You mentioned the process is very slow. How are you inserting the data into your database? Generally bulk inserting is much faster than inserting 1 record at a time.

Comment: @christian-Küpers  If you use Microsoft SQL Server, another option is to use BULK INSERT. When I've performed this, I've had to use local or UNC paths. (A VIEW or FORMATFILE may be required too.) The result is much, much faster compared to attempting to read the file, loop and issue millions of UPDATE queries. It's acceptable if only the VARCHAR values are quoted like your current one row sample. Otherwise CF could encounter memory limit or a timeout. With BCP (or SQL BULK INSERT), the import is almost immediate w/little-to-no negative impact to CF.

Comment: @james Moberg: Thanks for the suggestrion; my problem is, that below the performance the memory for csv into query was the limit. we started with a csv of 1.5mb; then it ran up to 5 mb with higher memory assignment. (we had to allocate more than 10GB memory)
But now the customer delivers a file of 127 MB... and nothing goes.
Do you have experience with such files by use of csv>query? That would be the easiest way.

Comment: detail is also, that customer due to problems to export files, exports fieldtypes not in the same manner. In one file we have mixed... varchar in quotation and without... depending on the decision, whether there might be a problem with the content... Awful. 
so we have to inspect each field and therefor the suggested bennadel - solution works great. but not fast....

Comment: @christian-Küpers We analyze csv files up to 30 mb using ben nadel's solution. What do you consider fast? Have you tried splitting the file into smaller files. It could be that analyzing 10 files 13 mb each will be much faster then analyzing one 127 MB file.

Comment: @christian-Küpers Could you check the files size and scan the first line or two to determine the complexity of the file and the use different sub-routines to handle it? Sometimes a BULK INSERT into a temporary table and then using REPLACE and importing/transforming the values into a different table is faster & less intensive than CFLOOP.  When I have worked w/large CSV files that I don't bulk import, I use OpenCSV (java) and set a long timeout.

Comment: Thanks for all comments. We have setup an opencsv-parser (which is able to give me chunks of the file as array) yet along an inmemory use of mysql.... will implement the routines by now and inform about our progresses and performance improvements so far

Answer (score 1):

The fastest method i ever used to process a csv file is cfhttp, but this is buggy and difficult to use in real life situations. To import csv feeds we use a function that saves the csv data into a query. Then we import the query data into our database.

Note: Using a CSV parser as James Moberg suggested is much likely must faster.

Source: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/498-parsing-csv-values-in-coldfusion-while-handling-embedded-qualifiers-and-delimiters.htm & http://cflove.org/2012/12/working-with-csv-files-in-coldfusion.cfm

```
<!--- Option 1: Fastest method but prone to error --->
<cfhttp url="http://www.sharecsv.com/dl/9096d32f98aa0ac671a1cca16fa43be8/SalesJan2009.csv" name="q">
<Cfdump var=#q#>

<!--- Option 2: Slower but more stable --->
<cfsavecontent variable="strCSV">"Kunde";"Vtr";"Name"<Cfloop from=1 to=100 index=i>
10000000;29;"xyz Company"</cfloop></cfsavecontent>


<cfdump var="#CSVToQuery(strCSV,";","""",true)#"/>  

<cffunction name="CSVToQuery" access="public" returntype="query" output="false" hint="Converts the given CSV string to a query.">
        <!--- Define arguments. --->
        <cfargument name="CSV" type="string" required="true" hint="This is the CSV string that will be manipulated."/>
        <cfargument name="Delimiter" type="string" required="false" default="," hint="This is the delimiter that will separate the fields within the CSV value."/>
        <cfargument name="Qualifier" type="string" required="false" default="""" hint="This is the qualifier that will wrap around fields that have special characters embeded." />
        <cfargument name="SetColumnName" type="boolean" required="false" default="true" hint="Set the column name based on the first row of the csv file" />

        <cfset var LOCAL = StructNew() />
        <cfset ARGUMENTS.Delimiter = Left( ARGUMENTS.Delimiter, 1 ) />

        <cfif Len( ARGUMENTS.Qualifier )>
            <cfset ARGUMENTS.Qualifier = Left( ARGUMENTS.Qualifier, 1 ) />
        </cfif>

        <cfset LOCAL.LineDelimiter = Chr( 10 ) />

        <cfset ARGUMENTS.CSV = ARGUMENTS.CSV.ReplaceAll("\r?\n",LOCAL.LineDelimiter) />
        <cfset LOCAL.Delimiters = ARGUMENTS.CSV.ReplaceAll("[^\#ARGUMENTS.Delimiter#\#LOCAL.LineDelimiter#]+","").ToCharArray() />

        <cfset ARGUMENTS.CSV = (" " & ARGUMENTS.CSV) />
        <cfset ARGUMENTS.CSV = ARGUMENTS.CSV.ReplaceAll("([\#ARGUMENTS.Delimiter#\#LOCAL.LineDelimiter#]{1})","$1 ") />
        <cfset LOCAL.Tokens = ARGUMENTS.CSV.Split("[\#ARGUMENTS.Delimiter#\#LOCAL.LineDelimiter#]{1}") />
        <cfset LOCAL.Rows = ArrayNew( 1 ) />
        <cfset ArrayAppend(LOCAL.Rows,ArrayNew( 1 )) />
        <cfset LOCAL.RowIndex = 1 />
        <cfset LOCAL.IsInValue = false />
        <cfloop index="LOCAL.TokenIndex" from="1" to="#ArrayLen( LOCAL.Tokens )#" step="1">
            <cfset LOCAL.FieldIndex = ArrayLen(LOCAL.Rows[ LOCAL.RowIndex ]) />
            <cfset LOCAL.Token = LOCAL.Tokens[ LOCAL.TokenIndex ].ReplaceFirst("^.{1}","") />
            <cfif Len( ARGUMENTS.Qualifier )>
                <cfif LOCAL.IsInValue>
                    <cfset LOCAL.Token = LOCAL.Token.ReplaceAll("\#ARGUMENTS.Qualifier#{2}","{QUALIFIER}") />
                    <cfset LOCAL.Rows[ LOCAL.RowIndex ][ LOCAL.FieldIndex ] = (LOCAL.Rows[ LOCAL.RowIndex ][ LOCAL.FieldIndex ] &LOCAL.Delimiters[ LOCAL.TokenIndex - 1 ] &LOCAL.Token) />
                    <cfif (Right( LOCAL.Token, 1 ) EQ ARGUMENTS.Qualifier)>
                        <cfset LOCAL.Rows[ LOCAL.RowIndex ][ LOCAL.FieldIndex ] = LOCAL.Rows[ LOCAL.RowIndex ][ LOCAL.FieldIndex ].ReplaceFirst( ".{1}$", "" ) />
                        <cfset LOCAL.IsInValue = false />
                    </cfif>
                <cfelse>
                    <cfif (Left( LOCAL.Token, 1 ) EQ ARGUMENTS.Qualifier)>
                        <cfset LOCAL.Token = LOCAL.Token.ReplaceFirst("^.{1}","") />
                        <cfset LOCAL.Token = LOCAL.Token.ReplaceAll("\#ARGUMENTS.Qualifier#{2}","{QUALIFIER}") />
                        <cfif (Right( LOCAL.Token, 1 ) EQ ARGUMENTS.Qualifier)>
                            <cfset ArrayAppend(LOCAL.Rows[ LOCAL.RowIndex ],LOCAL.Token.ReplaceFirst(".{1}$","")) />
                        <cfelse>
                            <cfset LOCAL.IsInValue = true />
                            <cfset ArrayAppend(LOCAL.Rows[ LOCAL.RowIndex ],LOCAL.Token) />
                        </cfif>
                    <cfelse>
                        <cfset ArrayAppend(LOCAL.Rows[ LOCAL.RowIndex ],LOCAL.Token) />
                    </cfif>
                </cfif>
                <cfset LOCAL.Rows[ LOCAL.RowIndex ][ ArrayLen( LOCAL.Rows[ LOCAL.RowIndex ] ) ] = Replace(LOCAL.Rows[ LOCAL.RowIndex ][ ArrayLen( LOCAL.Rows[ LOCAL.RowIndex ] ) ],"{QUALIFIER}",ARGUMENTS.Qualifier,"ALL") />
            <cfelse>
                <cfset ArrayAppend(LOCAL.Rows[ LOCAL.RowIndex ],LOCAL.Token) />
            </cfif>
            <cfif ((NOT LOCAL.IsInValue) AND (LOCAL.TokenIndex LT ArrayLen( LOCAL.Tokens )) AND (LOCAL.Delimiters[ LOCAL.TokenIndex ] EQ LOCAL.LineDelimiter))>
            <cfset ArrayAppend(
                LOCAL.Rows,
                ArrayNew( 1 )
                ) />
            <cfset LOCAL.RowIndex = (LOCAL.RowIndex + 1) />
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>

    <cfset LOCAL.MaxFieldCount = 0 />
    <cfset LOCAL.EmptyArray = ArrayNew( 1 ) />

    <cfloop index="LOCAL.RowIndex" from="1" to="#ArrayLen( LOCAL.Rows )#" step="1">
        <cfset LOCAL.MaxFieldCount = Max(LOCAL.MaxFieldCount,ArrayLen(LOCAL.Rows[ LOCAL.RowIndex ])) />
        <cfset ArrayAppend(LOCAL.EmptyArray,"") />
    </cfloop>
    <cfset LOCAL.Query = QueryNew( "" ) />
    <cfloop index="LOCAL.FieldIndex" from="1" to="#LOCAL.MaxFieldCount#" step="1">
        <cfset QueryAddColumn(LOCAL.Query,"COLUMN_#LOCAL.FieldIndex#","CF_SQL_VARCHAR",LOCAL.EmptyArray) />
    </cfloop>

    <cfloop index="LOCAL.RowIndex" from="1" to="#ArrayLen( LOCAL.Rows )#" step="1">
        <cfloop index="LOCAL.FieldIndex" from="1" to="#ArrayLen( LOCAL.Rows[ LOCAL.RowIndex ] )#" step="1">
            <cfset LOCAL.Query[ "COLUMN_#LOCAL.FieldIndex#" ][ LOCAL.RowIndex ] = JavaCast("string",LOCAL.Rows[ LOCAL.RowIndex ][ LOCAL.FieldIndex ]) />
        </cfloop>
    </cfloop>

    <Cfif SetColumnName>
        <cfloop query="LOCAL.Query" startrow="1" endrow="1" >
            <cfloop list="#LOCAL.Query.columnlist#" index="LOCAL.col_name">
                <cfset local.field = LOCAL.Query[col_name]>
                <cfset QueryChangeColumnName(LOCAL.Query,col_name,field) >
            </cfloop>
        </cfloop>

        <cfset LOCAL.Query.RemoveRows( JavaCast( "int", 0 ), JavaCast( "int", 1 ) ) />
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn LOCAL.Query />
</cffunction>


<cffunction name="QueryChangeColumnName" access="public" output="false" returntype="query" hint="Uses java to rename a given query object column">
      <cfargument name="queryObj" required="true" type="query">
      <cfargument name="oldColName" required="true" type="string">
      <cfargument name="newColName" required="true" type="string">

      <cfset var colNameArray = queryObj.getColumnNames()>
      <cfset var i = 0>

      <cfif arrayLen(colNameArray)>
            <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(colNameArray)#" index="i">
                  <cfif compareNoCase(colNameArray[i],arguments.oldColName) EQ 0>
                        <cfset colNameArray[i] = arguments.newColName>
                  </cfif>
            </cfloop>
      </cfif>

      <cfset queryObj.setColumnNames(colNameArray)>

      <cfreturn queryObj />
</cffunction>
```